# Are there results on cardinal function using o-tightness?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, cardinal-characteristics

Recall that a space $X$ has countable $o$-tightness, if for every family $\mathcal U$ of open sets of $X$
and for each $x \in X$ with $x \in \overline{\bigcup \mathcal U}$, there exists a countable subfamily
$\mathcal V \subset \mathcal U$ and $x\in \overline{\bigcup \mathcal V}$.

It is easy to see that, the $o$-tightness of any space having countable tightness or countable chain condition is countable. As we know, there are many cardinal functions involving tightness or chain condition. However, I searched for the results of $o$-tightness in many papers and books, and it seems there are very few.

So let me ask the

> **Question.** Are there any results on cardinal function using (countable)
> $o$-tightness?